# Number theory: a quote

Tags: reference-request, number-theory, quote, book-recommendation

I remember reading a remark on number theory that went something like this: "there is plenty of material in this topic for an $n$ semester course without having to repeat oneself".

Have you read a sentence of this type once? If so, would you be so kind as to tell me where it is that I can find it? Quite possibly, in the version of the quote that I originally read the writer had $n=100$.

Thanks in advance for your help with this little question of mine.

Cheerio!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"It has been estimated that, at the present stage of our knowledge, one could give a
200 semester course on commutative algebra and algebraic geometry without ever
repeating himself." These are the opening lines of the Foreword to Ernst Kunz' book *An Introduction to Commutative Algebra and Algebraic Geometry.*